# Angular how to convert a text string to html objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

Under my Angular app :

i ve a string like the following :

```
let mystr : "<p>Ceci c'est un texte aléatoire de test <a href='https://codemirror.net' title='https://codemirror.net' target='_blank'>ceci c'est un simple HYPERLINK</a> Ceci c'est un autre texte aléatoire de test Ceci c'est un autre texte aléatoire de test <a title='' target='_blank' href='http://testing.com/book.html?default=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>'>Un autre hyperlink </a></p><p>Ceci c’est un hyperlink copié sur la même page:</p><p><a href='https://aaa.bb.tes.com/aide-et-support/fiche-assistance/31516/une-page-grise-saffiche-a-louverture-dun-fichier-excel-2010' title='se rendre sur la page Une page grise s’affiche à l’ouverture d’un fichier – Excel 2010'><span style='color:blue;'>Une page grise s’affiche à l’ouverture d’un fichier – Excel 2010</span></a></p>"
```

My purpose , is how to convert that string to html objects and manipulate them in typescript

(beofre appending them to the DOM with **innerHtml**)

And then be able to modify them before displaying in the view ;

For example i want to change all the titles attributes of all  tags within that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example:

```
const mystr : "<p>Ceci c'est un texte aléatoire de test <a href='https://codemirror.net' title='https://codemirror.net' target='_blank'>ceci c'est un simple HYPERLINK</a> Ceci c'est un autre texte aléatoire de test Ceci c'est un autre texte aléatoire de test <a title='' target='_blank' href='http://testing.com/book.html?default=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>'>Un autre hyperlink </a></p><p>Ceci c’est un hyperlink copié sur la même page:</p><p><a href='https://aaa.bb.tes.com/aide-et-support/fiche-assistance/31516/une-page-grise-saffiche-a-louverture-dun-fichier-excel-2010' title='se rendre sur la page Une page grise s’affiche à l’ouverture d’un fichier – Excel 2010'><span style='color:blue;'>Une page grise s’affiche à l’ouverture d’un fichier – Excel 2010</span></a></p>"
    
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = mystr;
    const allA = el.querySelectorAll('a');
    
    allA.forEach(a => console.log(a.getAttribute('title')));
```

and so forth...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) for this

```js
const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<h1>Hi</h1>','text/html')
const h1 = dom.querySelector('h1')
h1.setAttribute('hidden', 'true')
console.log(h1) // <h1 hidden="true">Hi</h1>
```